# Changing default version of R used when opening an R terminal VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'm opening an R terminal in VSCode, but relying on renv and a specific version of R I have on my PC. The current terminal loads the newest version. Easy way to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the specific R executable  launched in the terminal with the setting `r.rterm.windows` (or `r.rterm.mac` or `r.rterm.linux` as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [rig](https://github.com/r-lib/rig) to manage the different R versions on your system. When you need a specific version, use `rig default <R version>` in the command line to set the one you need to use with a specific project and change back (e.g. using `rig default release`) once you're done.